# How to debug custom MavenPublication in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I'm working on a Gradle project (with plugin `maven-publish`) that has a lot of convoluted logic for custom `MavenPublication`s. I would like to look under the hood of the task `publish`. In particular, I would like to check the metadata of any/all `MavenPublication`s, without actually running the task `publish`.

I know how to do some of the debug printing for regular tasks, but as far as I know, `maven-publish` plugin generates the tasks on the fly for every artifact+repository pair. Maybe there is a simple way to iterate over all `MavenPublication`s? In an `afterEvaluate` block, for example.

Perhaps I could get enough information from running `publishToMavenLocal` and checking `~/.m2`, but it is very time consuming to iterate using `publishToMavenLocal` due to project size – it would be much faster to debug print the information about `MavenPublication`s.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to debug tasks in some IDEs, for example in IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#debug_gradle

Gradle also provides documentation on this:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting.html#sec:troubleshooting_build_logic

In fact, the Gradle docs above debug exactly what you are trying to do.